# How to get a list of system users in vlang?

Tags: cross-platform, account, vlang

I am trying to list all the system users, I know that on Linux I could use
`awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd` and on Windows I could use `wmic useraccount get name` but I was wondering if there was function in V that would be better suited for it and didn't require different commands for Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You can now use `fn user_names() ?[]string` from the `os` module in order to get the names of users on the system.

There currently is now way to get a list of users on the system. However you can you compile time if statements to execute the commands you referred to above.

```
import os

fn main() {
    $if windows {
        result := os.execute('wmic useraccount get name')?
    } $else $if linux {
        result := os.execute('awk -F: "{ print $1 }" /etc/passwd')?
    } $else {
        println('unsupported os')
    }
    // do something with result
}
```

Comment: This does look very useful though. Keep an eye out on the `os` module in the documentation. I might make a pull request adding this feature.